# What is the purpose of the keyword “||” in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to figure out what does the operator `||` mean?

Google didn't help with that...

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/index.html - worth reading.  This you will find in several sections of _9. Functions and Operators_

Comment: It's the standard SQL operator to concatenate strings.

Comment: ... and in PostgreSQL, concatenate tsvectors, OR tsquerys together, array-to-array concatenation, element-to-array concatenation and array-to-element concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation as you can see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html

Array concatenation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html

And others... It means: concatenation.